# ldapwhoami not sending out traffic according to tcpdump

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, terraform, tcpdump

I'm using Terraform to deploy a setup in GCP where there is a Windows VM running active directory (being the domain controller) and another Linux VM running an application.  The application needs to authenticate with the domain controller using a user's credentials, so I put in a bash script that waits until the user has been created before starting the application.  The script looks like this:

```sh
    until ldapwhoami -H ldap://${var.domain_controller_ip} -D ${var.service_account_username}@${var.domain_name} -w ${var.service_account_password} -o nettimeout=1 > /dev/null 2>&1
    do
      echo 'Waiting for AD account. Retrying in 10 seconds...'
      sleep 10
    done
```

The intention here is this will keep looping until the user has been created in the domain controller, at which point the loop exits and continues with starting the application.

This script is run in the context of a Terraform SSH provisioner so that I can monitor what's going on from the Terraform host, and so that the next step doesn't start until this loop exits.

Most of the time this script works - meaning that shortly after the user has been created in the domain controller, the loop in the Linux VM would exit and carry on.  However, a lot of times, I see the Linux VM getting stuck in the loop waiting for hours, unable to successfully perform the "ldapwhoami" eventhough the user has already been created. During these times, I notice the following:

1. If I start another SSH session into the same Linux VM and execute the exact same command, `ldapwhoami` is able to authenticate successfully - all this while the loop is still failing and retrying.
2. If I start another SSH session into the same Linux VM and start a `tcpdump host [domain_controller_ip]`, I would see no traffic from the loop - meaning that `ldapwhoami` failed without even sending any packets out to the network. (Normally `tcpdump` would show the packets during successful cases)

I'm really puzzled why `ldapwhoami` is sometimes not even sending out packet to the domain controller. Is there some local cache somewhere? If so how can it be flushed?

Another observation is that if I haven't seen this problem if I run the same loop as part of the startup-script instead of inside an SSH provisioner (though it's hard to monitor progress that way).  Perhaps this is a problem with the SSH provisioner?

Any help is appreciated!

edit: When it gets stuck in the loop, there is also a chance that it automatically recovers (meaning exiting the loop) after something like 40+ minutes (normal successful case should take about 15 mins waiting for the user), but sometimes it doesn't recover for hours.

Comment: A host doesn't communicate with itself over the wire. It's all done in memory. Off topic.

Comment: Why are you so certain that it's `ldapwhoami` that's failing to talk on the wire?  It might well be that (on occasion, for whatever reason) some of the variables you're throwing its way aren't populated, in which case it will fail to do **ANYTHING**; you'll never find out because you're discarding its output.

Comment: @user207421 - I don't think you quite read the question properly; if the linuxVM talks to a windowsVM it's not talking via sockets, but through a virtual network interface known to the kernel as such, and usable by `tcpdump`.

Comment: The linux vm talks to the windows vm using the internal IP address assigned by GCP.  I shortened the script in this question for readability, but in the actual script, I do echo out the variables (as well as the entire command for debugging) so I'm pretty sure the ldapwhoami command got the correct variables.

Comment: And its output?

Comment: The output just shows the actual values of my variables so I know they are not somehow wrong:  `ip=10.0.0.100, user=cam_admin@example.com`

Comment: I mean the output `> /dev/null 2>&1` you're nonchalantly discarding, not the debug output you're explicitly printing ...

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem but have yet to run into it again.  Will post once I hit it again - have gone about 20 times without hitting that problem so far.